# eclipse not showing errors

Tags: eclipse

I have a java project open in eclipse. I can see in one java class a bunch of errors, but eclipse Problems view does not show any problem.

where do we configure the filtering of which errors to show in the Problems view, and which we don't?

Comment: this is probably for stackoverflow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm currently working with Eclipse 3.6.1, but this was in a similar place in earlier versions. There's a small downward triangle in the upper right conerer of the Problems view. Clicking that brings up a menu with "Configure Contents..." as one of the options. This will let you change what's showing up in the view.

If the errors don't seem correct or aren't updating properly, you may need to refresh the project, run a clean/rebuild on the project, or close the java file and re-open it.

Comment: cheers.. I was looking in the preferences and couldn't find anything!

Answer (score 3):

You need to open the eclipse Markers view (`Window->Show View->Markers`), it will show all errors about your project, if you correct all the errors, your problem will most likely be solved.

Answer (score 0):

- In Eclipse close the Markers view, close the Problems View
- Re-Open Markers view, re-open the Problems View
- in both views go to "Configure Contents..." and restore to Defaults Settings (button at the left bottom of the dialog)

Then the missing items will re-appear (so they did at least on my Eclipse 4.4.0 installation)